# How can I create a dynamic method on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I create a dynamic method like the `GetNameAttribute` from laravel

I want a method called `ReturnWith` that can receive a string as parameter `ReturnWith($string)` and if I call `ReturnWithProduct` what is after ReturnWith should become the parameter, so `ReturnWithProduct` becomes `ReturnWith('product')`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) when you need load multiple relations.

you can call `with` by array like this:

```php
with([$relation, $relation1, $relation2]);
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer becomes confused, I'll remake it